# Script terminates with PermissionError [Error 13] when reading a large file

Tags: python

Yeah I know this or *similar questions* have been posted to this forum but so far none of the answers is sufficient to solve my problem:

Here I have the following code:

```
with open(filename,'r',buffering=2000000) as f:
    f.readline()                # takes header away
    for i, l in enumerate(f):   # count the number of lines
        print('Counting {}'.format(i),end='\r')
        pass
```

What happens is the file is a 23Gbytes  csv file. I get the following error:

```
File "programs\readbigfile.py", line 33, in <module>
    for i, l in enumerate(f):  # count the number of lines
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

The error always happens at the line number `1374200`. I checked the file with a text editor and there is nothing unusual at that line. This happened to me with the same file but a smaller version (a few less Gigabytes). Then suddenly it worked.
**The file is not being used by any other process at all.**

Any ideas of why this error occurs in the middle of the file?

PD. I am running this program on a computer with an Intel i5-6500 CPU/16Gb memory and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti card.
System is Windows 10. **Python 3.7.6 x64**/Anaconda
The file is on a local disk, no networking involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the error is due to a file writing error, either because a bad disk block or a disk system failure. The point is, the file had a [**CRC error**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) somewhere in the middle of it, which I corrected just by creating the file again. It is a random error so if you find yourself in the same situation, one of the checks should be the **soundness** of the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is, I think your code is ok.

My ideas:

- do you need this buffering? Did you try to remove it completely?
- I see you're running on Windows. I don't know if that's important, but many weird issues happen on Windows
- if you're trying to access it on a disk in the network (samba etc), maybe it's not fully synced?
- are you sure nothing else tries to access this file in the meantime? excel?
- did you try reading this file with `csv.reader`? I don't think it'd help though, just wondering
- you can `try/except` and when the error is raised check `os.stat` or `os.access` if you have permissions
- maybe printing is at fault, it sounds like a huge file. Did you try without printing? You might want to add `if i % 1000 == 0: print(...)`

Comment: Thank you for your input! I may try taking the printing away but then I wouldn't know where the error occurs :) Well I tried without the printing: The error occurs only faster this time.

Comment: unless you add `try/except: print...` :)